# Calculo de tempo logado no SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, lógica

Tenho um sistema em que usuário loga e desloga da ferramenta várias as vezes no dia durante seu horário de trabalho. Preciso calcular a quantidade de tempo em que o mesmo ficou logado:

As colunas `LOGOUT` e `LOGIN` são em segundos.

```
SELECT DATA,USUARIO,SUM(PERIODO_LOGADO) AS TOTAL_LOGADO
FROM (
    SELECT DATA,USUARIO,LOGOUT-LOGIN AS PERIODO_LOGADO
    FROM HISTORICO_LOGIN
    GROUP BY DATA,USUARIO,LOGOUT-LOGIN
) SUB
GROUP BY DATA,USUARIO
```

Esta consulta funciona, porém existe o caso de funcionários que trabalham na madrugada, e acabam tendo o tempo contabilizado em dias separados.

Como unir os dois tempos ou calcular o total de horas trabalhadas de forma dinâmica?

Comment: nao entendi o lance das colunas LOGOUT e LOGIN, elas são do tipo data? Elas marcam a data de Login e a data de Logout, é isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma saída é tu criar uma `CASE WHEN` na sua data interna pra quando ela for de madrugada tu retorna dia-1. Partindo do princípio que você quer agrupar até as 6h da manhã do dia seguinte.

```
SELECT DATA,USUARIO,SUM(PERIODO_LOGADO) AS TOTAL_LOGADO
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, DATA) < 6
                THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATA)
                ELSE DATA 
           END AS DATA,
           USUARIO,LOGOUT-LOGIN AS PERIODO_LOGADO
    FROM HISTORICO_LOGIN
    GROUP BY DATA,USUARIO,LOGOUT-LOGIN
) SUB
GROUP BY DATA,USUARIO
```